# How to prevent fatal error of memory size exhaustion

Tags: php, mysql, memory-management

I am retrieving 10K records (having 10 columns with datatypes as `datetime`, `text`, `int`, `varchar`) using `mysql_fetch_object` and fetching all columns from each joined table in the query , which gave the memory size exhaustion fatal error, but then I amended the query to get only some specific columns which eliminated the error, saving me from drowning in the lake of errors.

The query is simply joining 3 tables, A, B, C as , `SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON ......JOIN C ON ...... WHERE.....`

But I am still in the fear that if the no. of records or no. of columns increase, then the error would appear again....so what would be the complete solution of this? I read other posts on SO, and found that `mysql_unbuffered_query` should be used. But is there no solution if I use `mysql_fetch_object`? Also will unbuffered query take more time as it returns one row at a time?

Comment: can you give us the **actual** code? if you want to optimize it, we need something to optimize. btw, this might be better on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: show the actual query. You could very well be producing a cartesian join, so your 10k records balloon into billions or trillions of rows.

Comment: no i executed the query in mysql and it literally returned 10000 rows

Comment: Do you have any LONGBLOB or LONGTEXT columns in your tables? PHP will try to pre-allocate enough memory to hold the largest possible string from those columns, not the length of the actual data. Which means it could be trying to allocate 4GB buffers, much in excess of PHP's default memory limit. Solution: use MEDIUMBLOB/MEDIUMTEXT instead.

Comment: @BillKarwin : am using the TEXT datatype, and the user can input any length input for that field so i can't limit the size of that

Comment: Are you sure that you need `*` on your query?

Comment: @sqlchild, TEXT cannot be longer than 64KB. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev : yes am sure about that

Comment: @BillKarwin : but if 10K rows are fetched, does this overuse the memory

Comment: @sqlchild, yes, if you are expecting large result sets, you should take care not to try to store it all in memory at the same time. That's the reason to use unbuffered queries so the client doesn't prefetch all the rows. Also, design your application code to process the rows one at a time instead of saving them in one big array in PHP space.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is not the one running out of memory here, it's your PHP script so reducing the size of the `SELECT` is only a partial solution.

My guess is that you're doing something like:

```
$collect = array();
while (has_records) {
    $collect[] = fetch_record;
}
foreach ($collect as $row) {
    handle_record($row);
}
```

Of course `$collect` will get very big. See if you can avoid collecting all records: Read a record, handle it, clean up memory and do the next iteration.

```
while (has_records) {
    var $row = fetch_record();
    handle_record($row);
}
```

---

Iterator sample code:

```
class DB {
    function get_iterator($query) {
        $query_result = do_query($query);
        return new Iterator($query_result);
    }
}

class MyIterator {
    public function __construct($mysql_result) {
        $this->res = $mysql_result;
    }
    public function hasMore() {
        // do some counting
    }
    public function fetch() {
        return mysql_fetch($this->res);
    }
}

echo '<table>';
$it = $db->get_iterator("SELECT * FROM `items`");
while($it->hasMore()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    $row = $it->fetch();
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
        echo '<td>' . $cell . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

You can even `implements Iterator` so you can `foreach` over `$it` directly, which is awesome.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, am using the method you posted

Comment: Ok, does this help you get to a solution?

Comment: This is actually a good idea. You could also split the queries to do them in batches of say 1k each.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen : am displaying the records in a table layout after fetching them into a single array, and the while loop is in the back end , acc. to your answer i have to add the UI part in the back end which I can't do

Comment: Yes you can, you're just not thinking in the right way. Rather than `$db->getMeData("rawr")` and it gives you the data (in an array) you can have it return an Iterator. I added some sample code.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen : sir, can you please post the front-end code too with a simple query : SELECT * FROM items , sorry for being a newbie

Comment: @FritsvanCampen : ok, so first i need to do this : $it = new DB(); then $it = new MyIterator()

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with classes this solution might be a little bit too advanced. Go read this :) http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: sir, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44718/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-frits-van-campen)